# When Enable row grouping, caption in Column Filter disappear

Tags: jquery, datatables

When Enable row grouping, caption in Column Filter disappear

My code is like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/trp14hxk/

```
...
    function initTable(hasRowGrouping){   
         $('#example').dataTable({
             "bDestroy": true,
             "bLengthChange": false,
             "bPaginate": false,
             "bJQueryUI": true,
             "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex){
                 $(nRow).css('background-color', /*oData.colour*/ '#99F');
             }
         }).columnFilter({
                sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
                aoColumns: [
                    { type: "text" }, 
                    { type: "text" },
                    { type: "text" }, 
                    { type: "text" }, 
                    { type: "text" }
                ]
            });
...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by modifying your *columnFilter* a bit as in this JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/trp14hxk/2/

```
...
  function initTable(hasRowGrouping){   
     $('#example').dataTable({
         "bDestroy": true,
         "bLengthChange": false,
         "bPaginate": false,
         "bJQueryUI": true,
         "fnCreatedRow": function (nRow, aData, iDataIndex){
             $(nRow).css('background-color', /*oData.colour*/ '#99F');
         }
     }).columnFilter({
            sPlaceHolder: "head:before",
            aoColumns: [
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
            ]
        });
...
```